# Get all the black text from a cell and put it into another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched online for answers to this and have found things which come close but really can't get them to work at all so have decided to cut my losses and ask the wonderful gurus on here :)

I have a workbook with five tabs.  The first four tabs record data about orders placed of different tabs - ie tab one records orders placed with business 1, tab two records business 2 and so on.

In each of the four tabs, there is a header row, and column A contains an ID, and column G contains freetext information about the actual orders placed, such as 'A&I, BHU, GUIDS, U&E'.  When we receive the items - which we do not receive all at once - we colour the relevant item a different colour in the cell.  So for this order, if we'd received the A&I and BHU, they would be a different colour, but GUIDS and U&E would still be black.  I know, it's a horrible format and I'm building a proper application to replace the whole dratted thing, but for now I can't change what we have.

What we need as an interim measure is a way to get outstanding orders.  I have set up worksheet number 5 for this.  It has a section for each of the other four tabs (I thought it would be easier to write a simpler process and redo it four times, once for each sheet).  Columns A and B have the headers 'ID' and 'Orders Outstanding' and relate to Business 1.  Columns D and E have the same headers but relate to Business 2 and so on.

What I need:  I need to go through column G in the 'Business 1' worksheet and for any cell which has some black text, return all of the black text as a string (cutting out any other colour) into one cell in column B of worksheet 5, and in column A of worksheet 5 return the ID (column A) which was in the same row on the business 1 sheet.

So far I have something like this but it's a load of rubbish really...(and doesn't compile)

```
Sub ProduceLateList()

    Dim r As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i1 As Integer
    Dim EmptyRow As Long

    EmptyRow = 0

    For Each r In Worksheets("Business 1").Range("G2").CurrentRegion
      For Each cell In r.Cells

        Dim sColoredText

        For i1 = 1 To Len(cell.Value)
            If (cell.Characters(i1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
                sColoredText = sColoredText & Mid(cell, i1, 1)
            End If
        Next i1

        With Worksheets("Worksheet 5").Range("A2")
            If sColoredText <> "" Then
                .Offset(EmptyRow, 1).Value = sColoredText
                .Offset(EmptyRow, 0).Value = Worksheets("Business 1").Cells(cell.r, 0).Value
            End If
        End With
        EmptyRow = EmptyRow + 1
      Next cell
    Next r

End Sub
```

This does now compile, after the help provided by JMax, and after I comment out the bit which is supposed to fill in my ID...

The problem is, it basically goes through EVERY SINGLE CELL in the range - not just the column G range - so I get triangular data.  in my results, I get in my first cell the first header cell text from A1 of Business1.  In the second cell of results I get the concatenated value of the first header cell + the second header cell of Business 1 (IE A1 and B1).  It goes on like this in an across-then-down format so my final line (quite a long time later) has essentially got all the text from the entire Business 1 worksheet into one cell...on one line...although in all fairness, it IS only giving me the black text!!!!!

I can't provide the original spreadsheet due to data sharing issues but I could probably mock something up which would give you the idea if it would help??

Please please please, any help would be so very very much appreciated - I am not a VB programmer and am really hoping a kind person out there will take pity on me and show me the light!!

Thank you so much

edit: a link to my dummy spreadsheet where you can see it in action!! (Hopefully...) - not my rubbish code but the nice stuff kindly provided by Tony Dallimore:
http://www.mediafire.com/?ndqu98giu4jjmlp

Comment: you shouldn't `Set` a Long (this is used for Objects only). So, at first, replace your 5th line with `EmptyRow = 2`

Comment: Thanks :)  It still doesn't work though but I will edit the original request to give more detail on what it currently does...

Comment: Assuming all items are filled in column G you could do this  Worksheets("Business 1").Range("G2", Worksheets("Business 1").Range("G2").End(xlDown))

Comment: Sadly they're not, there are some blank cells.  I know - rubbish data...... :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have read your question more carefully.  On first reading I had not noticed you only wanted to analyse data in column G and had not noticed the need to copy the value from Column A.

I cannot achieve that by amended your code.  I have commented it out in case you want to look at it and have added a new loop.  I hope this is closer to what you seek

```
Sub ProduceLateList()

  Dim r As Range
  Dim i1 As Integer
  Dim EmptyRow As Long
  ' It is always best to type variables.
  ' You cannot declare variables inside a loop with VBA.
  ' Why the name sColored text when it is to contain
  ' non-coloured text?
  Dim sColoredText As String

  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim Id As String

  ' Set is only for Objects
  EmptyRow = 2
  ' This will delete any existing values in Worksheet 5
  ' except the header row
  With Worksheets("Worksheet 5")
    .Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(Rows.Count)).EntireRow.Delete
  End With
  With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    ' Find last used row in column G
    RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row
  End With

  For RowSrcCrnt = 2 To RowSrcLast
    With Worksheets("Business 1")
      With .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, "G")
        sColoredText = ""
        If IsNull(.Font.Color) Then
          ' Cell is a mixture of colours
          If IsNumeric(.Value) Or IsDate(.Value) Then
            ' Cannot colour parts of a number or date
          Else
            ' Analyse this multi-coloured text
            For i1 = 1 To Len(.Value)
              If (.Characters(i1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
                sColoredText = sColoredText & .Characters(i1, 1).Text
              End If
            Next i1
          End If
        Else
          ' Cell is a single colour
          If .Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
            ' Entire cell is black
            sColoredText = .Value
          End If
        End If
      End With
      If sColoredText <> "" Then
        Id = .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, "A").Value
      End If
    End With
    If sColoredText <> "" Then
      With Worksheets("Worksheet 5")
        .Cells(EmptyRow, "B").Value = sColoredText
        .Cells(EmptyRow, "A").Value = Id
        EmptyRow = EmptyRow + 1
      End With
    End If
  Next

  'For Each r In Worksheets("Business 1").Range("B2").CurrentRegion
  '  ' Without this, sColoredText just gets bigger and bigger
  '  sColoredText = ""
  '  ' r.font.color will return Null if the cell have a mixture
  '  ' of colours.  No point examining single characters if the
  '  ' whole cell is one colour.
  '  If IsNull(r.Font.Color) Then
  '    ' Cell is a misture of colours
  '    ' It is not possible to colour bits of a number or a date
  '    ' nor is it possible to access individual characters
  '    If IsNumeric(r) Or IsDate(r) Then
  '      ' Cannot colour parts of a number or date
  '    Else
  '      ' Analyse this multi-coloured text
  '      For i1 = 1 To Len(r.Value)
  '        If (r.Characters(i1, 1).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)) Then
  '          ' You can only use Mid to access sub-strings within a
  '          ' string or variant variable.
  '          sColoredText = sColoredText & r.Characters(i1, 1).Text
  '        End If
  '      Next i1
  '    End If
  '  Else
  '    ' Cell is a single colour
  '    If r.Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0) Then
  '      ' Entire cell is black
  '      sColoredText = r.Value
  '    End If
  '  End If
  '  ' I have moved the If sColoredText <> "" Then because
  '  ' you do not need to look at the destination sheet
  '  ' unless it contains something.
  '  If sColoredText <> "" Then
  '    ' I find your use of offset confusing.  I have replaced it
  '    ' with Cells(row,column)
  '    With Worksheets("Sheet5")
  '      .Cells(EmptyRow, "B").Value = sColoredText
  '      ' r is a single cell range.  You do not need to do
  '      ' qualify it to get its value.
  '      .Cells(EmptyRow, "A").Value = r.Value
  '      EmptyRow = EmptyRow + 1
  '    End With
  '  End If
  'Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this incredibly helpful piece of code.  Sadly it still doesn't work - I will mock up a copy of the file without any sensitive data and upload it as I think this may help!!

Comment: I have a worksheet full of numbers and text in a variety of colours (mixed and unmixed) which I need for another project.  My code extracts the black text and not the coloured text which, as I understand it, is what you want.  So please explain "doesn't work".

Comment: Okay well I only want the black text values which are given in column G of "Business 1" to be put into Column B of "Worksheet 5". When it puts the value of the entire black character string from the cell (lets say G2 from "Business 1") into - for example - B2 of "Worksheet 5", I ALSO want it to put the value which is in cell A2 of "Business 1" into cell A2 of "Worksheet 5".

However, the data your function gives...I will put in another comment as I've gone over quota :)

Comment: It goes through the data of the business 1 tab perfectly and is a vast improvement for me, as well as showing me some things so I really do appreciate your help with this.  What your function does, though, is give me the following data in "Worksheet 5":

1) I get two columns of data but instead of the ID from "Business 1" and the text value, I get the same data twice
2) I don't only get the stuff from column G.  I get all black text from the entire range on "Business 1" (range being all the data entered)

I really really really really do appreciate all of your help already on this though!!!

Comment: Okay I have mocked up a simple spreadsheet with your code in it which shows my scenario and only then realised I can't attach it to the question.  Duh!!!  Link to follow...

Comment: I have reread your question more carefully and have reposted my answer.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect, thank you so very much for bearing with me and being so helpful - I have marked this as the answer

Comment: You are welcome. Sorry I did not read your question more carefully first time.  Thanks for the acceptance.